# Number of ways to choose 30 nonadjacent edges from Truncated Icosahedron

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, coloring, solid-geometry

While working with a molecular design of Buckminsterfullerene C60 which I can relate to Truncated Icosahedron, I found an interesting fact. If you see the picture below it has 30 yellow edges that are representing double bonds and 60 red edges that are representing single bonds. The rule here is every 60 vertex should connect to 1 yellow edge (double bond) and 2 red edges(single bonds). Until now I thought the model below was the only solution that satisfies the rule.

[image]

However I recently found another model that is linked to Wikipedia page as an interactive 3D model that has a different arrangement. You can see some yellow edges(double bonds) on a pentagon side whereas in the first model all edges making up pentagons were red(single bond).

[image]

Although edges(bonds) can be arranged in many different ways, eventually they satisfy these rules:

1. Total number of yellow edges(double bonds) are exactly 30.
2. None of the 30 yellow edges(double bonds) shares the same vertex with one another. In other words, none of the yellow edges(double bonds) are adjacent to each other.

But for the sake of this question, distinguishing between single bonds and double bonds or coloring them seems irrelevant.

So my question is:

How can I get the total number of ways to choose 30 edges from Truncated Icosahedron so that all chosen edges are nonadjacent? While counting all the arrangements that can be derived by rotating another arrangement as 1.

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fullerene_chemistry#Chemical_properties_of_fullerenes.

Comment: Your question is equivalent to finding the number of unique perfect matchings on the truncated icosahedral graph up to edge-preserving permutations of its vertices.

Comment: @joriki  Thanks a lot for the link.. but I am not able to understand those sophisticated chemistry explanations..  T.T   while designing 3D model of this molecule this question popped up and I had no luck after hours of researching into this so I asked here.

Comment: @heropup  Hmm.. I thought this was a simple enough question that with the right keywords I could find a formula or papers..  I couldn't find anything with your keyword either yet. 

I tried solving a much simpler version of this problem which is "the number of ways you can choose nonadjacent 4 edges from a cube", and I found 2 of them. One of which has 3 duplicates you can rotate around, another one has 6.  So apparently if I don't have full understanding of symmetry I can't simply divide the number by a symmetry value to get my answer after brute-force checking.

Comment: @DominicJung: I wasn't implying that that solves your problem or that you shouldn't have asked here (I think here was the right place to ask); I just wanted to share what I found that seemed relevant. As to your last comment above, check out Burnside's lemma. (And just as I'm writing this, Robert Z posted an answer that uses Burnside's lemma...)

Comment: @DominicJung "I recently found another model that is linked to Wikipedia page as an interactive 3D model that has a different arrangement"  Where is the link?

Comment: @RobertZ  Ah sorry.  Here's the link.  [link](https://chemapps.stolaf.edu/jmol/jmol.php?model=C13%3DC4C9%3DC8C%2526%3DC1C2%3DC%2527C7%3DC6C%2529%3DC2C3%3DC%2530C5%3DC4C%2510%3DC%2511C%2521%3DC5C%2531%3DC%2520C%2517%3DC%28C6%3DC%2516C%2523%3DC7C%2528%3DC%2524C%2514%3DC%28C8%3DC%2513C%28%3DC9%2510%29C%2512%3DC%2511C%2522%3DC%2518C%2515%3DC%2512C%2513%3DC%2514C%2525%3DC%2515C%2519%3DC%28C%2516%3DC%2517C%28%3DC%2518%2519%29C%2520%3DC%2521%2522%29C%2523%3DC%2524%2525%29C%2526%3DC%2527%2528%29C%2529%3DC%2530%2531)

Comment: Ah, nice. Note that you can rotate it to get a better look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a partial answer. According to Hosoya's paper [Matching and symmetry of graphs](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0898122186901549), the number of perfect matchings on the truncated icosahedral graph is equal to 
$$2^2\cdot 5^5=12500.$$
How many of them are distinct up to rotations?

The rotation group $G$ of the truncated icosahedron has $60$ elements:

- identity
- 12 rotations by 72°
- 12 rotations by 144°
- 20 rotations by 120°
- 15 rotations by 180°

Hence, by [Burnside's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_lemma), the number of *distinct* matchings is
$$\frac{12500+\sum_{g\in G, g\not=\text{id}}|\text{Fix}(g)|}{60}.$$

Computing $|\text{Fix}(g)|$, i.e. the cardinality of the set of matchings which are invariant by $g$ for each $g\in G$ when $g$ is not the identity might be a bit annoying.

P.S. The matching given in your first picture is invariant for all $g\in G$. On the other hand, the matching given in your second picture is not invariant for the 12 rotations by 72° and for the 12 rotations by 144°.

Comment: The matching in the first picture is indeed invariant, since it consists of exactly the bonds that are not part of pentagons, and that description is invariant.

Comment: @joriki I agree. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: @RobertZ  Thanks a lot for the answer and the linked research paper. It helped me understand this better.  :)    before I choose the answer for the question though, I'd to clarify one more thing.   $$ 2^2 * 5^5=12500 $$  is the number of perfect matching, and a comment(by heropup) on my question said what I asked is actually getting the number of "UNIQUE perfect matching".   So I can conclude that the upper bound of the answer I was looking for is 12500.  Right?

Comment: @DominicJung Yes, you are correct.

Comment: @RobertZ  Wow!  Finding out that the upper bound for my answer was 12500 is also pretty amazing.  Seeing how big  Combination(90, 30)  is ==which is about 6.73 * 10^23==  I thought the number of perfect matching would be in trillions, and unique perfect matchings would also be at least a few millions.

Anyway, thanks a lot for your answer. It really helped!  :)